# Can I "start over" a java Scanner?

Tags: java, kotlin, io, java.util.scanner

Is there a way to make a scanner start from the beginning of its input, again?

Context: I just learned that https://adventofcode.com/ is a thing.

The first task is simple enough (as first tasks often are).

You're given a series of sign-prefixed (`+` or `-`) integer values

I.e.

```
-7
+16
+5
[...]
```

and need to add them.

No big deal.

**task01.kts**

```
import java.util.*

val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

private var total = 0
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    val number = scanner.nextInt()
    total += number
}

println(total)
```

The second task states that the read input is repeated over and over again and that we're interested in the first `total` to be reached twice.

Again, fairly simple:

**task02.kts**

```
import java.util.*
import java.io.File
import Task02.Result.*

sealed class Result{
    object None: Result()
    data class Found(val duplicate:Int):Result()
}

if(args.size < 1) throw IllegalStateException("please provide input file as first arg")

val input = File(args[0])

private var total = 0
private val seen = mutableSetOf(0)

private var result: Result = None
while(result is None){
    val scanner = Scanner(input)
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        val number = scanner.nextInt()
        total += number

        if(seen.contains(total)){
            result = Found(total)
            break;
        }
        else seen.add(total)
    }
}

println((result as Found).duplicate)
```

But one interesting difference between the two tasks is that while I don't care where the numbers come from in the first part, I *need* a `File` for the second.

And it got me thinking. Is there a "wrap-around scanner" or something?

Can I manually *reset* the Scanner's pointer?

Or can I *chain* Scanners such that everything the first scanner sees (including the stuff it skips over) gets passed on to the second?

You know, that kind of thing?

```
       Scanner1                    Scanner2
[ O | L | L | E | H ]        [   |   |   |   |   ]
[   | O | L | L | E ]        [   |   |   |   | H ]
[   |   | O | L | L ]        [   |   |   | E | H ]
[   |   |   | O | L ]        [   |   | L | E | H ]
[   |   |   |   | O ]        [   | L | L | E | H ]
[   |   |   |   |   ]        [ O | L | L | E | H ]
```

or anything else along these lines?

I have a hunch there isn't because most everything I could think of would require the caching of all input (which, depending on the input size, may not be reasonable), but I'm still curious if I haven't overlooked something.

Comment: Dou you want to read same data and process it twice for first and second exercises?

Comment: Or what is the reason to start over a scanner?

Comment: @Pavel the second exercise requires reading the same input over and over again until eventually, a ``total`` is reached that was already reached once.

Comment: I misunderstood that `total` can decrease as well. Now it's clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If scanner can be resetted, there will be two possibilities:

1) Each time you reset, it starts reading from the file again. It does not give any benefits over creating a new one each time.

2) It saves all read data in RAM. But you can save it by yourself as well. Often it will be more efficient. In the case you can store integer instead of string which saves memory.

If you want just don't close&reopen the file each time, you can use some lower-level file-specific API like [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) which can be reset using `seek(0)`.

The reason that `Scanner` does not have `seek` method is that it accepts not only file but any `InputStream` like `System.in` which can't be read again by design.

Answer (score 1):

If you just plan on reading the same input repeatedly then open it as a `RandomAccessFile` and `seek` back to the start on each iteration.

Of course your algorithm is assuming a constrained input. What do you do if the input consists of one line containing "+1"?

Comment: Well, then I keep looping forever. I *did* assume that if the task is to get to a duplicate ``total``, there is one. But you're right, if I cannot make that assumption, I'd probably have to cut the loop at some point and state that I couldn't reach a duplicate in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: It would eventually hit an over- or underflow depending on the sign.But you are likely to get `OutOfMemory` before then. You know that duplicate totals can only be reached when the sign swaps (no dups in monotonic order), then you can kind of fold the numbers back on themselves and look for where they match (same distance).

Comment: Care to elaborate on that "fold the numbers back on themselves" bit?

Comment: When I say "(no dups in monotonic order)", this is of course not true if input is `0`. I'm talking about if the increase or decrease is in only only direction

Comment: In my minds eye I see it as a kind of XY plot. X: 0..oo, for every input the plot moves in the positive X direction and the Y is offset by the input value. If the sign of the input is different from he running total you get a sharp kink. Unless you have at least one such kink (or zeros) you won't have a dup total.